# Best Map for interned Strings

Tags: java, collections

I have a large number of interned strings (with a small number of possible values, so it makes sense to intern them) that I want to store in a `Map` (to use as a counter).

The `TreeMap` does a comparison at each level of the tree, which I imagine would involve an O(n) comparison of characters. `HashMap` will use the hash to bucket.

Given that I have a small set of interned Strings, which means that reference can be used for equality or ordering comparison (so neither the hash code nor the value need to be used), I wonder if there's a well-suited structure?

(Or indeed a more specialised one suited to counting)

My priorities are both speed and compact representation (I'm dealing with a large amount of data).

(To head off any "premature optimisation" comments, I'm processing about 200 million items).

Comment: Would `IdentityHashMap` help ?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html

Comment: Thanks @Berger that's exactly what I was looking for. I overlooked it in the javadocs for some reason. As Clashsoft's answer says, there's nothing magical about it (as confirmed by my experimentation).

Comment: your goal is to count how many times each unique string occurred in input data?

Comment: are the values known (ex. fixed number of statuses) or not?

Comment: If you're thinking of an `EnumMap`, then no. They're not known at compile time.

Comment: i think of checking just first bytes (e.g. strings are AAA, BBB, CCC, str[0] is A and you know its AAA) and then increment the counter. if you're calling String.intern in your code before putting to map, it's no faster than simply putting to map.

Comment: That's a really good thought AdamSkywalker, thank you. I am interning primarily because there are a large number of these counters, so it makes sense to share memory for keys between them.

Comment: What I suggested is a sort of Huffman algorithm. The problem with intern is that JVM has to lookup your string in its string table, and it takes time anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### IdentityHashMap

The [`java.util.IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) works similarly to the `HashMap` class, but uses identity equality `==` and hash code (`System.identityHashCode`) to compare keys. It also has a much smaller memory footprint because it only uses a single array to store both keys and values. Although `==` is as fast as it gets, the [`System.identityHashCode(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)) method has a `native` implementation that carries some overhead (but it probably is a JVM intrinsic).

#### HashMap

The `HashMap` implementation, although it requires more memory (`HashEntry`s), should have a similar performance for hash code computation and equality checks. This is due to the fact that the `String.equals` method checks for reference equality at first, and `String.hashCode` is cached for every String. In an 'emergency', the `HashMap` approach will also produce correct results for non-cached Strings. In terms of maintainability, this might be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I think I'm looking for. Although for 1 million entries it takes about the same amount of time. I'll try a few things out.

Comment: IdentityMap is a little quicker - 60 seconds for 1 million entries against HashMap's 70 seconds. An array-based O(n) implementation I hacked together has about the same performance (60 seconds). I think the differences are within error margins for my uses, but good to know about.